# How do I write dictionary inside a DataFrame as an element?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Is it possible to write a dictionary into Data Frame? I have created the following DataFrame with my structure:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'name': ['L1', 'L2'], 'DEF': [None, None]})

df
Out[70]: 
  name   DEF
0   L1  None
1   L2  None
```

I also have a dictionary

```
dict1={'DEF120':50}
```

If try to write dictionary into df as

```
df.loc[df.name=='L2', 'DEF'] = dict1
```

I am getting NaN as

```
df
Out[76]: 
  name   DEF
0   L1  None
1   L2   NaN
```

But! If I write a random number, then it works!

```
df.loc[df.name=='L2', 'DEF'] = 1323213

df
Out[78]: 
  name      DEF
0   L1     None
1   L2  1323213
```

Can someone please explain what is the problem here? Why does writing dictionary not work?

Thanks!

Comment: try str(dict1) when assigning not just dict1 it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries/lists have a special meaning when assigned using `loc`. Pandas will try to expand them to Series.

You need to cheat a bit and use `at`:

```
s = df.name=='L2'
idx = s[s].index[0]
df.at[idx, 'DEF'] = dict1
```

updated dataframe:

```
  name             DEF
0   L1            None
1   L2  {'DEF120': 50}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
>>> df.at[1, 'DEF'] = dict1
>>> df
  name             DEF
0   L1            None
1   L2  {'DEF120': 50}
```

This way you can get the value `50` by doing:

```
>>> df.loc[df.name=='L2', 'DEF'].str['DEF120']
1    50
Name: DEF, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass dictionary as list or use `np.where` or `Series.mask`.

```py
df.loc[df.name=='L2', 'DEF'] = [dict1]
# or
df['DEF'] = df['DEF'].mask(df.name=='L2', dict1)
# or
df['DEF'] = np.where(df.name=='L2', dict1, df['DEF'])
```

```
print(df)

  name             DEF
0   L1            None
1   L2  {'DEF120': 50}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do this like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dic = {"1st_entry":"hallo","2nd_entry":"good by"}
data = [1,2,3,dic]
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

will result in

```
                                                0
0                                               a
1                                               b
2                                               c
3  {'1st_entry': 'hallo', '2nd_entry': 'good by'}
```

You have to find the right method to enter the data